# file exists but Perl -e test says not

Tags: perl

I'm getting a strange result checking for file existence with -e.

This is the first time I use Perl on my M1 Mac and the first time I use 5.30.2. Did something change?

Any hints very welcome.
Chris

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.30.2;

print "\nTest001.pl (5.30.2 on M1 Mac)\n\n";
my $file = "\~/Documents/XWM10/Dic13.txt";
print "\$file set to $file\n\n";
print "Trying if(-e \$file):\n";
if (-e $file) {
    print "$file exists\n";
}
else {
    print "$file does NOT exist!\n";
    print "\nTrying ls -l \$file:\n";
    system ("ls -l $file");
    print "\n";
}
```

...and the output:

```
user@Blue2 ~ % ~/Documents/XWM10/Test001.pl

Test001.pl (5.30.2 on M1 Mac)

$file set to ~/Documents/XWM10/Dic13.txt

Trying if(-e $file):
~/Documents/XWM10/Dic13.txt does NOT exist!

Trying ls -l $file:
-rw-r--r--@ 1 user  staff  2243467 Sep 18 11:03 /Users/user/Documents/XWM10/Dic13.txt

user@Blue2 ~ %
```

Comment: Almost certainly the `~` is not being expanded.  Never use `~` except interactively.

Comment: Instead, use `my $file = "$ENV{HOME}/Documents/XWM10/Dic13.txt"`

Comment: Yup! It was the tilde of course. /Users/user fixes it. I'll use full-path in future. Thanks for the rapid response. Chris